# Edit file line by line

Tags: php

I'm making a program that reads a file line by line and deletes the lines that say `Hand #[any numbers]`

```
$file_name = 'the_file.txt';
$file_handle = fopen($file_name,"r+");

while(! feof($file_handle)) {
    $file = fgets($file_handle);

    if (preg_match("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/m", $file)) {
        fwrite($file_handle, preg_replace("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/m", "", $file));
    }
    
  }

fclose($file_handle);
```

This code does nothing however if put `echo $file . '<br />';` It prints every line with `Hand #[any numbers]` So think its a problem with `fwrite($file_handle, preg_replace("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/m", "", $file));` Which work fine if the file is not read line by line.

Comment: How big are these files

Comment: @ohgodwhy needs to handle any size but mostly a few megabytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing to a different file than you are reading from. It's possible that PHP doesn't like you trying to overwrite parts of the file as you're reading from it.

Also double-check that the PHP script has permission to write to the file.  Try something simple like make a backup of it and then do `file_put_contents($file_name, 'test');`

Answer (score 0):

It can be related to the file pointer position and also to the fact that you are writing to the file, and not deleting anything. See function http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php

So you are not deleting a line but writing a new line in the place after the line you have just read (which is left in place). In this case it's better to write in different file.

Answer (score 0):

You want to exclude all lines that start with "Hands #number" ?
Then why do you use preg_match to find the lines, to write them replaced by nothing to the file? Just exclude them and keep the lines you want in an array. Or open a secondary file and write each line directly to the new file, if memory limits are an issue.

```
$filename = "the_file.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r+") or die("Could not open $filename" . PHP_EOL);

$keep = array();
while(!feof($handle)) {
    $line = fgets($handle);
    if(!preg_match("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/m", $line)) {
        $keep[] = $line;
    }
}
rewind($handle);
fwrite($handle, implode(PHP_EOL, $keep));
fclose($handle);
```